# A (probably) simple explanation - constructor definition and argument(s)

Tags: c#, class, constructor

I've seen this question asked a few times and can't seem to get my head around why this isn't working.  Please help a noob (and be gentle!). I'm simply trying to create a class to accept the name of a COM port and then start a serial object on that port. I keep getting a "Conex does not contain a constructor that accepts 1 argument" error, though it seems to me that's all it contains. Thoughts?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace Conex_Commands
{

    public class Conex
    {
        string NewLine = "\r";
        int BaudRate = 921600, DataBits = 8, ReadTimeout = 100, WriteTimeout = 100;
        Parity Parity = Parity.None;
        StopBits StopBits = StopBits.One;


        public Conex(string PortName)
        {
            SerialPort Serial = new SerialPort(PortName, BaudRate, Parity, DataBits, StopBits);
            Serial.ReadTimeout = ReadTimeout;
            Serial.WriteTimeout = WriteTimeout;
            Serial.NewLine = NewLine;
        }



    }


}
```

The calling code contained in my main is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Conex_Commands;


namespace Tester
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Conex abc = new Conex("COM5");
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: please also show the calling code that gives you the error, not only the Conex class.

Comment: Are there two types both named Conex? Is the code which does the construction in the same assembly as the class you show here?

Comment: check that you compiled the project - if it's 'left out', unchecked in configuration manager

Comment: Added the call - it is certainly compiling and is checked in the configuration manager.

Answer (score 0):

Is this just for debugging purposes?

My VS2010 code shows no errors with this code.

It is, however, useless as written because as soon as you call the constructor for `Conex`, the `SerialPort` goes back out of scope.

Instead, bring your `Serial` object outside of the constructor:

```
public class Conex {
  string NewLine = "\r";
  int BaudRate = 921600, DataBits = 8, ReadTimeout = 100, WriteTimeout = 100;
  Parity Parity = Parity.None;
  StopBits StopBits = StopBits.One;
  SerialPort Serial;

  public Conex(string PortName) {
    Serial = new SerialPort(PortName, BaudRate, Parity, DataBits, StopBits);
    Serial.ReadTimeout = ReadTimeout;
    Serial.WriteTimeout = WriteTimeout;
    Serial.NewLine = NewLine;
  }

  public void Open() {
    Serial.Open();
  }

  public void Close() {
    Serial.Close();
  }

}
```

Now, from within your `Main` routine, you can actually attempt to Open and Close the connection (which threw an Exception on my PC, because it has no "COM5" port):

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  Conex abc = new Conex("COM5");
  abc.Open();
  abc.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I found my bonehead move - I was working out of the original .cs and it wasn't updating to the reference that I had placed within the tester program - no wonder it was throwing the number of arguments error!